# AngularJs Ui route not working?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

Hi I was advised to use ui-router due to having problems with nested views.

I'm trying to create a form like this to go in the middle of my page.

[the form](http://plnkr.co/edit/Zh0BrzSO9EzKTAe3Ywom)

However it doesn't work and it's made my website not being able to load properly.  I cannot view anything from the header down.  The logo and the header works...but No body and no footer.  Form pages are in partials/form.html etc.  The body and footer loaded fine before I edited the code to include the forms.

Here's my plunker [my app](http://plnkr.co/edit/jOhp3CY8iF10Cx7QxXBm?p=catalogue)

here's index.html

```
<html ng-app="financeApp">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
 <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>




<header>
   <div class="wrap">
     <!-- logo -->

   <a href="#!"><img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" /></a>
</div>


<body ng-controller = "demoCtrl">




 <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
  <li ng-class="{active: isState('home') }">
    <a ui-sref="home">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li ng-class="{active: isState('form') }">
    <a ui-sref="form">Form</a>
  </li>
  <li ng-class="{active: isState('contact') }">
    <a ui-sref="contact">Contact</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <h3 class="text-muted">Demo Page</h3>
 <br>
 <div ui-view=""></div>




</div>




 <!-- Loading the Footer -->
 <div id="footer" ng-include="'partials/footer.html'"></div>



<!-- App JS -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.min.js"></script>
 <!--  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-route.min.js">    </script>-->
  <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-animate.js">  </script>-->
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.min.js">    </script>

<script src="js/script.js"></script>

<!--<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.15/slick.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js"> </script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives/directives.js"></script>
<link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
   <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.1.1"      src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Your tag <body> is at the wrong place, it must be the main tag of the document

Comment: @Thierry, I guessed this is the root cause, but I fixed it in plunker and issue still exist

Comment: And <header> is not closed. Have you checked the js console?

Comment: Changed the body tag, closed the <header>...issue still persists?

Comment: Footer now works but form is non existent.